# Asp.net - DropDownLists in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I was trying to make a column of DropDownLists in GridView from the C# code, to no avail. Here is the code I use:

```
var manager=Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("Roles", typeof(DropDownList));
            var a = manager.Users.ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++ )
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Email"] = a[i].Email;
                dr["Username"] = a[i].UserName;
                DropDownList lista = new DropDownList();
                var b = manager.Users.ToArray();
                lista.DataSource = b;
                lista.DataBind();
                dr["Roles"] = (DropDownList)lista;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

                GridView1.AutoGenerateSelectButton = true;

            dt.AcceptChanges();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

The first 2 colums show up, the last (which should have DropDownLists) does not. Why?